# Firebase Database Listener returns null value

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this database, wher I need to read the value for previous `transitTransactions` under `transaction_status`, if it is`null`, the user populates under the node `transaction_user`, if not`null` just reads the data from the node, to avoid uploading the same data again.
The nodes under `transaction_status` are created with Firebase Functions triggered by OnCreate under `transaction_user/{uId}/{key}`, and is meant to be read only by any user.

```
    private void checkForPreviousTransactions(TransitTransaction transitTransaction) {
        String key = transitTransaction.getKey();
//        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("transaction_users").child(userId).child(key).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("transaction_status").child(key).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.getValue() ==null) {
                    HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
                    result.put("is_delivered", false);
                    result.put("is_in_transit", true);
                    result.put("is_processed", false);
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("transaction_users").child(userId).child(key).updateChildren(result);
                } else {
                    isDelivered = (boolean) dataSnapshot.child("is_delivered").getValue();
                    isInTransit = (boolean) dataSnapshot.child("is_in_transit").getValue();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.e(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

[image]
My problem is that the first time a `transaction_user` is created, the function is triggered creating a `transaction_status`; when I close the application and open it again the code will run looking for previous transactions but the value returns `null` recreating everything again, including the function trigger, but the next time I open the application the value is not`null` as I'd expect to be the very first time.

This are the rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "transaction_users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    },
    "transaction_status": {
      "$transactionId": {
        ".read": "auth !=`null`",
        ".write": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Why does it returns`null` the first time, I can see the value in the database but still it returns`null`, this only happens the very next time after being uploaded by the user, second and onwards will return the proper value.

Is it that the `transaction_status` are created by Functions?

Does it has anything to do with the Rules?

Is something related with the Asynchronous nature of Firebase database?

How can I ensure that will read it properly the very first time that I listen for that value?

If I try checking on the value created by the user it returns non`null` the first time.

Additional Info:
I have:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

and:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("transaction_users").keepSynced(true);
```

Comment: Both `isDelivered` and `isInTransit` will be null until data changes in your database, yes. You should instead update some UI element or call some other function rather than assign those to fields and expect them to be assigned before Firebase completes any actions. In other words, "returning" is likely happening **after** you observe the value

Comment: @cricket_007 I disagree, that is the purpose for the `ListenerForSingleValueEvent`, to fetch a value once and not to keep listening for changes. In some other cases I use a `ValueEventListener` when I'm waiting for changes to occur.

Comment: I didn't say anything about waiting for continuous updates. Your listener must do a network operation over the internet. It will not "return" immediately... It's not clear where you are getting null, though

Comment: The first time I check on that Reference, I expect to get a `null` value, so it will set a value in a different reference, which in turn will trigger a `OnCreate` Function on that will write `read-only` data for every user. The second time I check on that reference I expect to get a `non-null` value, this is supposed to happen when the user reopens the app, not immediately, but here I get a `null` value even though the value is "visible" there. When the app is opened again and check the reference for a third time, it does return a `non-null` value.

Comment: My question is **where** and **what** are you seeing null? You've shown one method with no log statements other than the error... Try logging the values **immediately after** you assign them

Comment: I get `null`, in the `dataSnapShot` from the anonymous `ListenerForSingleValueEvent` where I do have a `ifelse` statement. Which is the node that is giving me trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
if (dataSnapshot.getValue() ==`null`)
```

to

```
if (dataSnapshot.exists())
```

From the official documentation regarding [exists()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#exists()) method:

> Returns true if the snapshot contains a non-null value, otherwise false.

Comment: I tried the `exist()` method but still the same result, the value which I see in the Realtime database, does not seems to exist the first time I try to fetch it after it has been created, the second time and onwards it returns a value, it returns as "exists"

Comment: So if the data does not exist for the first time, `dataSnapshot.exist()` should return `false`. If you create in the meanwhile an entry, the second time should return `true`, is this what is happening?

Comment: Yes, the first time I expect a false, which will cause my method to create an entry under `transaction_users`, when this is created a Function triggers and creates the entry under `transaction_status` which is read-only for any user.
If at this point I close the app and reopen it the first time the value under `transaction_status` returns `null` or `!exist`, even when I know that there is a value there.
At this point if I reopen the app, it will return a `not null value`.

Comment: This means that you are creating that entry in another location that you are checking it. The method returns `true`/`false` accordingly with it finds at that location.

Comment: I'm creating the entry via Functions in the same location I'm looking for. The first time I look for that entry I expect a `false`, so the entry can be created. The second time I look for that entry I expect a `true`, so the entry won't be overwritten by Functions, however here returns a `false`. The third time and onwards it returns `true` as expected.

Comment: It means that by the time your are checking the second time, your entry insn't yet created in the database and that's why you are getting `false`. Try to change the logic of your code like this: `check if exists` -> `if not, add entry` -> `check again`, as separate operations.

Comment: Yes, exactly, but the data is "visually" there, I even have waited up to 10 minutes to check if it a "matter of time" to return `true`.
And if I try to check for to listen for the commented line in the post it works just as expected. Why? I added two more lines to my post at the end.

Comment: The problem in you code is that you don't know when the data is written to server and for that I recommend you `addOnCompleteListener` to your write operation so all the other operations will take place, only when the write operation is complete, right?

Comment: Can't use an `OnCompleteListener`, because the data is written by a Function triggered by `OnWrite` with the purpose of making it read-only for everybody, I need to understand why this is happening.

Comment: This is the only way in which you can know for sure when the data is written completely in database. The reason is because the `write operation` takes time while you are checking it immediately. By the time you are checking the data isn't written yet in the database. Is clear now?

Comment: This check is intended to happen when the app is opened only, the check is not immediately, the only way I can think on checking write completion is implementing a `Callable Function`and somehow I believe I'll get the same result. Yes, is clear now.

Comment: It seems like now it's "exists()", not "exist()"

Comment: @Parsa That's correct, I just updated my answer. Thank you, Parsa.